# How to programmatically create literals using Eclipse AST

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, abstract-syntax-tree, eclipse-jdt

How to create different types of objects and literals using Eclipse AST?

i.e. To create primitives like `'c', 1, 1.5f`.
     To create objects literals like `new Employee('str')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `AST` class, here's a [documentation](http://help.eclipse.org/kepler/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/reference/api/org/eclipse/jdt/core/dom/AST.html) for it.

For example creating a `StringLiteral` which contains `Hello World` phrase.

```
AST ast = newAST(AST.JLS4)
StringLiteral literal = ast.newStringLiteral();
literal.setLiteralValue("Hello World");
```